# VueJS - requiring and rendering a component programmatically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a bit of a specific usecase here. I have a large Vue app with lots of pages. Each page has a page-id to identify it on the server and load it's content. These ids are in the router path (`parent-id/child-id/another-child-page-id`). On the page components themselves I display a page title. Unfortunately, there is no correlation between the translation key of the page title to the page-id.

Now, instead of creating a mapping between page-ids and page title translations that I will have to maintain by hand, I figured I could lookup the route in the router config and require the component:

```
{
  path: 'the-page',
  name: 'ThePage',
  component: resolve => require.ensure([], () => resolve(require('@/pages/ParentPage/ChildPage/ThePage')), 'parent-page')
}
```

This works by recursively walking through the routes to find the page-id, then loading the component in a promise:

```
// find the route definition
const route = findRouteByPath(file.areaName)
// load the route component
new Promise(resolve => { route.component(resolve) })
.then(component => {
  console.log(component)
})
```

This gives me the component like so:

```
Object {
  mixins: Array(1),
  staticRenderFns: Array(0), __file: "/the/file/path.vue",
  beforeCreate: Array(1),
  beforeDestroy: Array(1),
  components: Object,
  mixins: Array(1),
  render: function (),
  // etc.
}
```

If I call the render function, I get an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_c' of undefined

What I want to do is programmatically render the component and grab the content of the slot `page-title` from the component.

Can anyone help with this?

**Update 1**

`Vue.extend()` then mounting seems to do what I want. The problem is, I get all kinds of errors because the pages depend on certain things being around, like the current route. I'm also a bit worried to trigger certain `created()` hooks that would trigger API calls and such. My current state is trying to get rid of mixins and hooks like so:

```
const strippedComponent = Object.assign(component, {
  mixins: [],
  components: {},
  beforeCreate: []
})
const Constructor = Vue.extend(strippedComponent)
const vm = new Constructor({})
```

But I'm not quite there yet.

**Update 2**
I ended up abandoning this and bit the bullet by adding a `meta: {}` object to each route where I store things like the page title translation key and other good stuff.

Comment: Do you use webpack? Try to replace this `new Promise(resolve => { route.component(resolve) })` by `System.import('nameOfFile.vue')`

Comment: I am using webpack, yes. The importing is not the problem, it's how to render the component programmatically and access the data in the slot.

Comment: How did you call the `render` function directly? The render function needs an parameter `createElement`. This might be the reason that `render()` won't work

Comment: @Chris Have you tried to use [Vue.extend](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend), then mount it?

Comment: @Elfayer Thanks, that brought me a step further!

Comment: When you say "this gives me a component like so" you show *two* components properties. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yeah, copy/paste fail from the browser dev tools